# rails console, local vs something like heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I know I can do things like run `rails console` and change user values in my local environment. How does this apply to something like my rails app when deployed to heroku? Can I use the rails console there?

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can, with Heroku Toobelt you can run `heroku run rails console`, more here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#console